# Datastax Java Driver Custom Retry Policy

Tags: java, database, cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver

I have written a custom retry policy class where I can pass no of retries driver will perform onWriteTimeout/onUnavilable/onReadTimeout.

```
public class CustomRetryPolicy implements RetryPolicy {


  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomRetryPolicy.class);

  @VisibleForTesting
  public static final String RETRYING_ON_READ_TIMEOUT =
      "[{}] Retrying on read timeout on same host (consistency: {}, required responses: {}, "
          + "received responses: {}, data retrieved: {}, retries: {})";

  @VisibleForTesting
  public static final String RETRYING_ON_WRITE_TIMEOUT =
      "[{}] Retrying on write timeout on same host (consistency: {}, write type: {}, "
          + "required acknowledgments: {}, received acknowledgments: {}, retries: {})";

  @VisibleForTesting
  public static final String RETRYING_ON_UNAVAILABLE =
      "[{}] Retrying on unavailable exception on next host (consistency: {}, "
          + "required replica: {}, alive replica: {}, retries: {})";

  @VisibleForTesting
  public static final String RETRYING_ON_ABORTED =
      "[{}] Retrying on aborted request on next host (retries: {})";

  @VisibleForTesting
  public static final String RETRYING_ON_ERROR =
      "[{}] Retrying on node error on next host (retries: {})";

  private static final String LOG_PREFIX = "DATASTORE-CASSANDRA";

  private final int readAttempts;
  private final int writeAttempts;
  private final int unavailableAttempts;

  public CustomRetryPolicy(int readAttempts, int writeAttempts, int unavailableAttempts) {
    this.readAttempts = readAttempts;
    this.writeAttempts = writeAttempts;
    this.unavailableAttempts = unavailableAttempts;
  }

  @Override
  public RetryDecision onReadTimeout(Request request, ConsistencyLevel cl, int blockFor,
      int received, boolean dataPresent, int retryCount) {


    RetryDecision decision = (retryCount < readAttempts && received >= blockFor && !dataPresent)
        ? RetryDecision.RETRY_SAME
        : RetryDecision.RETHROW;

    if (decision == RetryDecision.RETRY_SAME && LOG.isTraceEnabled()) {
      LOG.trace(RETRYING_ON_READ_TIMEOUT, LOG_PREFIX, cl, blockFor, received, false, retryCount);
    }

    return decision;
  }



  @Override
  public RetryDecision onWriteTimeout(Request request, ConsistencyLevel cl, WriteType writeType,
      int blockFor, int received, int retryCount) {
    RetryDecision decision = (retryCount < writeAttempts && writeType == DefaultWriteType.BATCH_LOG)
        ? RetryDecision.RETRY_SAME
        : RetryDecision.RETHROW;

    if (decision == RetryDecision.RETRY_SAME && LOG.isTraceEnabled()) {
      LOG.trace(RETRYING_ON_WRITE_TIMEOUT, LOG_PREFIX, cl, writeType, blockFor, received,
          retryCount);
    }
    return decision;
  }

  @Override
  public RetryDecision onUnavailable(Request request, ConsistencyLevel cl, int required, int alive,
      int retryCount) {
    RetryDecision decision =
        (retryCount < unavailableAttempts) ? RetryDecision.RETRY_NEXT : RetryDecision.RETHROW;

    if (decision == RetryDecision.RETRY_NEXT && LOG.isTraceEnabled()) {
      LOG.trace(RETRYING_ON_UNAVAILABLE, LOG_PREFIX, cl, required, alive, retryCount);
    }

    return decision;
  }

  @Override
  public RetryDecision onRequestAborted(Request request, Throwable error, int retryCount) {
    RetryDecision decision =
        (error instanceof ClosedConnectionException || error instanceof HeartbeatException)
            ? RetryDecision.RETRY_NEXT
            : RetryDecision.RETHROW;

    if (decision == RetryDecision.RETRY_NEXT && LOG.isTraceEnabled()) {
      LOG.trace(RETRYING_ON_ABORTED, LOG_PREFIX, retryCount, error);
    }

    return decision;
  }

  @Override
  public RetryDecision onErrorResponse(Request request, CoordinatorException error,
      int retryCount) {
    RetryDecision decision =
        (error instanceof ReadFailureException || error instanceof WriteFailureException)
            ? RetryDecision.RETHROW
            : RetryDecision.RETRY_NEXT;

    if (decision == RetryDecision.RETRY_NEXT && LOG.isTraceEnabled()) {
      LOG.trace(RETRYING_ON_ERROR, LOG_PREFIX, retryCount, error);
    }

    return decision;
  }

  @Override
  public void close() {

    // Nothing to do

  }



}
```

I am using datastax java driver 4.6.0.
But the problem is I cant pass object of this class with CQLSessionBuilder,which is possible via like

```
RetryPolicy rc = new CustomRetryPolicy(3, 3, 2);
Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("192.168.0.0").withRetryPolicy(rc).build();
```

in older versions of driver. I have tried with DriverConfigLoader but there is only option to pass the custom class name.

Could you please suggest .

Answer (score 3):

If you look to implementation of [DefaultRetryPolicy](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/4.x/core/src/main/java/com/datastax/oss/driver/internal/core/retry/DefaultRetryPolicy.java#L86), and example of [CustomRetryPolicy](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/4.x/osgi-tests/src/main/java/com/datastax/oss/driver/api/osgi/CustomRetryPolicy.java#L23), you'll see that both are receiving 2 parameters: `context` of type `DriverContext`, and string with profile name.  And then you should be able to use `context` to get `DriverConfig` via `getConfig` call, and then use `getProfile` on config to pull configuration values that are required for your custom policy - you can put your own configuration values into configuration file and use it inside your retry policy, something like this:

```
datastax-java-driver {
  advanced.retry-policy {
    class = DefaultRetryPolicy
  }
  profiles {
    custom-retries {
      advanced.retry-policy {
        class = CustomRetryPolicy
        custom-policy {
           read-attempts = 3
           write-attempts = 2
           ...
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alex , Is it possible to pass the values rather than pulling it from  config file , I have a interface that will feed the retry attempts and I am trying to create custom retry policy based on these values , and use it while creating CqlSession itself.

Comment: you can also specify configuration properties programmatically, and then merge configuration from application.conf with configuration created programmatically

Comment: Thanks,If I understood your response correctly I dont want to take retry attempts from appliation.conf like you mentioned in your answer rather I want to set it pragmatically [because they will come from an interface]  in  DriverConfigLoader and then load the configloader -  withConfigLoader(loader) while creating the session.

Comment: configuration to driver may come from multiple sources, and combined together, so you can set your specific things programmatically, with the rest coming from application.conf & reference.conf. You maybe would need to upgrade to latest version of the driver - I remember some problems with programmatic loader around 4.6.0